# Reading Database, scraping Barchart and uploading prices to DB

Tags: python, beginner, sql, sql-server

This is my first real excursion into Python, coming from C#. I wanted to see if my code is well-formatted and efficient.

The following will read the needed codes from a Database Table, then submit the codes to an API, store them in individual objects, and then dump them back into another table in the Database.

```
import ondemand
import pyodbc
import datetime

#Code purposes
#1.) Get the desired barchart codes for the year
#2.) Load quotes into an array from Barchart API
#3.) Submit quotes to database for today's date

#Qute Class - Stores the quotes as objects
class Quote():
    def __init__(self, seq_dimDate, symbol, month, year, price, crop, ficalYear):
        self.seq_dimDate = seq_dimDate
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.price = price
        self.crop = crop
        self.fiscalYear = ficalYear


#Establish a connection to the database
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyComputer\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=MarketDB')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#get the Date and Fiscal Year
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
dateRow = cursor.execute('SELECT * from dbo.dimDate WHERE [Date] = ?', now).fetchone()
seqDimDate = dateRow.Sequence
fiscalYear = dateRow.FiscalYear
print('Sequence for %s is %s with a fiscal year of %s' % (now, seqDimDate, fiscalYear))

#Query the Barchart Codes Table
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM dbo.Codes WHERE [Year] = %s' % (fiscalYear))


#Generate a list of codes to send to API
quotesToQuery = ''

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    for x in range(3,len(row)):
        quotesToQuery = quotesToQuery + ',' + row[x]


#Open connection to the API
od = ondemand.OnDemandClient(api_key='123', end_point='https://marketdata.websol.barchart.com/')

#Get quotes
quotes = od.quote(quotesToQuery)['results']
lQuotes = []

#load the quotes into our array of objects
for q in quotes:
    #Get the Symbol, month, year and price of the quote
    symbol = q['symbol']
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(q['tradeTimestamp'], '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00-%H:%M')
    month = dt.month
    year = dt.year
    price = q['lastPrice']

    #Get the Sequence for the Crop
    if q['name'] == 'Corn':
        crop = 1
        price = price / 100
    elif q['name'] == 'Soybean Meal':
        crop = 2
    else:
        crop = 3

    #create a new Quote object and add it to the collection
    nq = Quote(seqDimDate, symbol, month, year, price, crop, fiscalYear)
    lQuotes.append(nq)

#Double Check of Quotes
print('%s total Quotes Collected' % (len(lQuotes)))

#Delete any Prices in the Database for this date sequence
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM dbo.MarketPrice WHERE Seq_dimDate = ?', seqDimDate)
cursor.commit()
print('MarketPrice table cleared of records with Date Sequence %s...' % (seqDimDate)) #confirm records were deleted

#Submit the Quotes to the Database
for n in lQuotes:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.MarketPrice (Seq_dimDate, Seq_Crop, [Month], FiscalYear, Price, Comments) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)', n.seq_dimDate, n.crop, n.month, n.fiscalYear, n.price, n.symbol)
    cursor.commit()
    print('%s Uploaded to MarketPrice Table in Hedging2' % (nq.symbol)) #confirm update
```

I submit myself to your critique!

Answer (score 1):

### Python review

This could make better use of docstrings and functions; for example, your comment about the `Quote` class should be a well-formatted docstring instead. Additionally, each of your different comment blocks would be best suited as a function, and then piece them together inside of a `__main__` block.

I would also do my best to remove any of your magic values, and instead use constants. This makes it easier if they come from somewhere else (e.g. a config file, or somewhere on the database) to adjust.

When formatting, prefer [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) over `%` formatting. If you're on a high-enough Python version, `f`-strings are even nicer.

This line is very magic: `for x in range(3,len(row))`. I would strongly prefer that you document what is going on here using non-magic numbers (and maybe a code comment). I *think* that what you're doing is getting the value from every column after the first 4; if that is what you're doing, then

1. Improving the SQL query is good to do here (see #1 in the SQL review below)
2. There are better variable names to use here

Generators are a good thing to use, as are list comprehensions. You can also use tuple-unpacking to make trivial assignments easier.

Instead of iteratively building a string, which performs poorly, use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). Similarly, instead of repeatedly `list.append`ing, use `list.extend` or a list comprehension.

Instead of cascading your `if`/`elif`/`else`, use a dictionary and a default value.

### SQL review

In general, your SQL is pretty straightforward so there isn't a ton to say. Overall, you should:

1. When `SELECT`ing something, only get what you need. `SELECT *` should always be considered suspect.
2. Avoid embedding raw SQL in your source code; if the desired behavior ever changes, now you're needing to update this code for no reason. A stored procedure (or table-valued function) is likely going to be a better option.
3. Always use your language/libraries tools for parameterizing SQL; you seem to switch back and forth between this and using string formatting. Always remember that no input is trusted, *even if it comes from your own database*.
4. Instead of inserting `VALUES` row-by-row, investigate if there is a bulk `INSERT` option for your library. If not, consider other options (as row-by-row is going to perform poorly)
5. Consider deleting and inserting in a single commit so as to avoid leaving the database in an unusual state in-between operations.

### Updated code

I came up with the following updates (that assume you have created the appropriate stored procedures, and I didn't bother with fully making all literals constants). I think there are a few more places for improvement here; for example, some of the formatting you do before instantiating the class could be done in the class itself (for example, a property that returns the formatted value, or a setter on that property that sets it in a formatted way). I also think you could likely break this up into a few more classes if you really wanted to make it OOP, but that is probably overkill for your use-case.
    """
    Gets barchart codes for a given year, then loads them into an array
    using BarChart's API. From there, the quotes are pushed to the database 
    using the current date
    """

```
import datetime

import ondemand
import pyodbc


CONNECTION_STRING = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyComputer\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=MarketDB"
API_KEY = "123"
END_POINT = "https://marketdata.websol.barchart.com/"
NAME_TO_CROP_MAPPING = {
    "Corn": (1, lambda price: price / 100),
    "Soybean Meal": (2, lambda price: price)
}
DEFAULT_CROP_MAPPING = (3, lambda price: price)


class Quote():
    """Stores the quotes as objects"""

    def __init__(self, seq_dimDate, symbol, month, year, price, crop, ficalYear):
        self.seq_dimDate = seq_dimDate
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.price = price
        self.crop = crop
        self.fiscalYear = ficalYear


def get_today_formatted():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")


def get_sequence_date(cursor):
    now = get_today_formatted()
    row = cursor.execute("EXECUTE dbo.RetrieveDateAndFiscalYear @dateFilter = ?", now).fetchone()
    return (now, dateRow.Sequence, dateRow.FiscalYear)


def get_codes(cursor, fiscal_year):
    FIRST_CODE_INDEX = 3

    all_codes = cursor.execute("EXECUTE dbo.RetrieveBarchartCodesByYear = ?", fiscal_year)    
    for row in all_codes.fetchall():
        for code in range(FIRST_CODE_INDEX, len(row)): 
            yield row[code]


def get_date_from_timestamp(timestamp):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00-%H:%M')
    return (date.month, date.year)


def get_quotes(od_connection, seq_dim_date, fiscal_year, quotes_to_query):
    raw_quotes = od_connection.quote(quotes_to_query)["results"]

    for raw_quote in raw_quotes:
        symbol = raw_quote["symbol"]
        month, year = get_date_from_timestamp(quote["tradeTimestamp"])
        base_price = q["lastPrice"]

        crop_id, adjusted_price = get_crop_sequence(q["name"], base_price)

        yield Quote(seq_dim_date, symbol, month, year, adjusted_price, crop_id, fiscal_year)


def get_crop_sequence(crop, base_price):
    crop_id, price_adjustor = NAME_TO_CROP_MAPPING.get(crop, DEFAULT_CROP_MAPPING)
    return (crop_id, price_adjustor(base_price))


def update_invalid_prices(cursor, seq_dim_date, quotes):
    cursor.execute("EXECUTE dbo.DeleteHistoricalPricesByDate @Date = ?", seq_dim_date)

    for quote in quotes:
        cursor.execute("EXECUTE dbo.UpdatePricesForQuote <<Fill in your parameters here>>", <<Fill in your parameters here>>)

    cursor.commit()

    print(f"MarketPrice table cleared of records with Date Sequence {seq_dim_date}...")
    print("\n".join([f"{q.symbol} Uploaded to MarketPrice Table in Hedging2" for q in quotes]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sql_connection = pyodbc.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)
    cursor = sql_connection.cursor()

    now, seq_dim_date, fiscal_year = get_sequnce_date(cursor)
    print(f"Sequence for {now} is {seq_dim_date} with a fiscal year of {fiscal_year}"))

    quotes_to_query = ",".join(get_codes(cursor, fiscal_year))
    ondemand_connection = ondemand.OnDemandClient(api_key=API_KEY, end_point=API_END_POINT)    
    all_quotes = list(get_quotes(ondemand_connection, seq_dim_date, fiscal_year, quotes_to_query))    
    print(f"{len(all_quotes)} total Quotes Collected")

    update_invalid_prices(cursor, seq_dim_date, all_quotes)
```